# How to convert an int value of days to its day and month value?

Tags: swift, date

If given the date value of 163 or some other integer I would like to convert it into that day's corresponding month and day. For example given 163 (the 163rd day of the year) I need to convert it into 06-12 for June 12th. How would I go about doing this in swift?

Answer (score -2):

Get beginning of year first.

```
    let calendar = Calendar.current
    var components = DateComponents()

    components.day = 1
    components.month = 1
    components.year = calendar.component(.year, from: Date())
    components.hour = 0
    components.minute = 0
```

add the desired number of days to the beginning of the year

```
    let beginningOfYear = calendar.date(from: components)
    let daysToAdd = 163
    let desiredDate = Calendar.current.date(byAdding: .day, value: daysToAdd, to: beginningOfYear)
```